# how to customize a webpack based app or library?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, customization

I hope I don't break any "best-practice" engineering stuff with this question, if so, I'll appreciate an answer of why...
So here it is:

I have a `JavaScript` app, `projectA`, which is a `react` application packed using `webpack` with the following output configuration:

```
output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'dist/[name].js',
    libraryTarget: 'umd'
},
```

Now, I want to be able to build another app or a module, let's call it `projectB`, which calls and uses the modules of `projectA`.

The challenge and the question is: how can I customize modules that I get from `projectA` to act differently while using them on `projectB`?

For example:

1. I have a screen from `projectA` in which I want to change a handler of a button.
2. In the screen from `projectA` I want to add more components to be drawn.
3. I want to replace an entire module from `projectA` with my own module which belongs to `projectB`

Assumptions:

- both of the projects are `react`-based applications
- both of the projects are packed using `webpack`
- I have full access to both of the projects' source code

This thread might be a discussion and not precisely have a single correct answer

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the first point, you cannot just replace a handler in a module you are using, when you import an outside module you shouldn't be aware of it's inner structures and behaviors. If you atill want this kind of behavior you can always have the handler of the button in ProjectA to be given as a prop.

Second point you wish to have will also grant you access to an inner behavior,  the rendering. Instead of seeking a possibility to add to this component in ProjectA on your ProjectB, the only way to resolve it that I could think of is either use children and render them directly as part of ProjectA class u wish to add to. Or use children and expose some wrappers to be used by the user of ProjectA.

Third point is also not reaonable, if in ProjectA its logical to be given the module you want from outside, as a prop, do so. Otherwise break down the component on ProjectA and construct it in ProjectB using some classes from ProjectA and some from ProjectB.